# Regex: extract all substrings with condition from string

Tags: python, regex

I have string, contains address

```
str_addr = '300114 г Тула, Тульская область, Ленинский р-он, п РАССВЕТ, 75, к.34, тульская обл, Краснодарский край, гагарина 38, республика Хакасия'
```

I need to extract

```
Тульская, тульская, Краснодарский, Хакасия
```

I try to use

```
re.findall(r"\b[А-Я]\w*\s+(?:[кК]рай|[оО](бласть|бл))|\b[рР](еспублика|есп)\s+[А-Я]\w*", str_addr)
```

but I get an empty list.

How can I fix that?

Comment: dont you need to activate unicode or something?

Comment: if you know what you need to extract, what new information do you expect `re.findall` to give you?

Comment: @Fallenhero in python 3 re.UNICODE is always set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
str_addr = '300114 г Тула, Тульская область, Ленинский р-он, п РАССВЕТ, 75, к.34, тульская обл, Краснодарский край, гагарина 38, республика Хакасия Москва, Санкт-Петербург'
res = re.findall(r"\b([А-Яа-яёЁ][^\W\d_]*)\s+(?:[кК]рай|[оО]бл(?:асть)?)|\b[рР]есп(?:ублика)?\s+([А-Яа-яёЁ][^\W\d_]*)|([мМ]осква|[сС]анкт-Петербург)", str_addr)
print(["".join(x) for x in res])
# => ['Тульская', 'тульская', 'Краснодарский', 'Хакасия']
```

See the [Python 3 demo](https://ideone.com/5tpRpu)

**Details**

- `\b([А-Яа-яёЁ][^\W\d_]*)\s+(?:[кК]рай|[оО]бл(?:асть)?)`:

  - `\b` - word boundary
  - `([А-Яа-яёЁ][^\W\d_]*)` - Group 1: a Russian letter followed with any 0+ letters
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `(?:[кК]рай|[оО]бл(?:асть)?)` - `Край`, `край`, `область`, `Область`, `обл`, `Обл`
- `|` - or
- `\b[рР]есп(?:ублика)?\s+([А-Яа-яёЁ][^\W\d_]*)`:

  - `\b` - word boundary
  - `[рР]есп(?:ублика)?` - `Республика` / `Респ` with variations
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `([А-Яа-яёЁ][^\W\d_]*)` - Group 1: a Russian letter followed with any 0+ letters
- `|` -  or
- `([мМ]осква|[сС]анкт-Петербург)` - Group 3: `Москва` or `Санкт-Петербург`.

The `["".join(x) for x in res]` list comprehension is used to drop empty values inside the returned list of tuples.

Comment: Thank you! If I want to find `Москва, Санкт-Петербург, Севастополь`, should i use `region = re.findall(r"\b([А-Яа-яёЁ][^\W\d_]*)\s+(?:[кК]рай|[оО]бл(?:асть)?)|\b[рР]есп(?:ублика)?\s+([А-Яа-яёЁ][^\W\d_]*)|[мМ]осква|[сС]анкт-Петербург|[сС]евастополь", str_addr)` ?

Comment: @PetrPetrov Since these are cities and not regions, why not run a separate regex? `re.findall(r'[мМ]осква|[сС]анкт-Петербург|[сС]евастополь', s)`?

Comment: they have a federal significance, so I need add it to region